# Reading Text File WIith Scanner (Java)

Tags: java, file, text, java.util.scanner

My Text file is called p1 and it contains:

```
p, -4, 5
q, 19, 8
r, 3, 0
x, 7.4, -1
y, -2.3,  -16.5
z, 0, 1
```

My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String fileName = "p1.txt";
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        System.out.println("The file " + fileName + "\ncontains the following lines: \n");
        
        try
        {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file " + fileName);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while(inputStream.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = inputStream.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        inputStream.close();
    }

}
```

For some reason my code can't read my text file and gives me the following output:

```
The file p1.txt
contains the following lines: 

Error opening the file p1.txt
```

I'm not sure what I need to do.

Comment: According to your code this message is written when file is not found: `catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file " + fileName);
            System.exit(0);
        }`. Your file should be in current working directory or absolute path should be used,

Comment: Once you have your file located, I would suggest using a BufferedReader to read a text file, rather than a stream.

Comment: A quick way to determine if you have the right file is to use File#getCanonicalPath(). You'd have to create your file object separately from the stream to use this.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your file `"p1.txt"` does not exists. Check the location of your file. It should be placed in same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that txt file is in the same folder as the project, if not give a path to it.